# image unable to write in resource folder of spring

Tags: java, spring, filestream

**This is my Service method**

```
public void CapchaString() {
                 String capchaString = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    //         ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(capchaString.getBytes());
                            try {
                               BufferedImage bi=new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                               Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
                               g.drawString(capchaString, 10, 10);
                              /* File outputfile = new File("src/main/resources/output.png");*/
                               ImageOutputStream out = new FileImageOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/Saurabh/Documents/Agile maple code/JavaJ2eeTraining/src/main/resources/output.png")); 
                               ImageIO.write(bi, "png", out);

                           } catch (IOException e) {
                               throw new RuntimeException(e);
                           }


            }
    }
```

This is my controller method

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/photo2", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public byte[] testphoto() throws IOException {
    capchaService.CapchaString();
    Resource resource = loader.getResource("output.png");

           ImageIO.createImageInputStream(resource.getFile());
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(resource.getFile()));
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
}
```

and when i use my server i am getting 
**HTTP Status 500 - class path resource [output.png] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist**

org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:177)
    org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:48)
    com.agilemaple.common.controller.HelloController.testphoto(HelloController.java:174)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to understand how a webapp works:

1. You setup a development environment and create sources. `src/main/resources` is part of this development environment.
2. you compile the sources and assemble them into a war file or exploded war directory
3. You deploy the war file to a server, which loads the classes and resources from the war file. Not from your development environment.

In production, all you have is the server, where the war file is deployed. There is no development environment on the server. The production server could be a linux server where paths like `C:/Users/Saurabh/` don't even make sense. Even if it's a windows machine, this directory doesn't exist on it. And even if it exists, the webapp doesn't load resources from there, but from the deployed war file, which is read-only.

So the above code doesn't make any sense. If you generate an image in the service, then return the bytes of the image from the method instead of trying to write it to a file and then reload the bytes from the file.

Comment: So the above code doesn't make any sense. If you generate an image in the service, then return the bytes of the image from the method instead of trying to write it to a file and then reload the bytes from the file.

can u elaborate this..u mean i should not write image and return bytes from my service method

Comment: You want to get an image bytes in your controller, from a service. So your service method should be declared as `byte[] CapchaString()`. It should return the bytes instead of writing them to a file. Use a MemoryCacheImageOutputStream writing to a ByteArrayOutputStream rather than a FileImageOutputStream, then return the ByteArrayOutputStream's bytes.

Comment: As an alternative, give to your service method a generic OutputStream to write to, then the caller will pass the HttpResponse OutputStream to it.  In this way the service method will write directly to the browser without knowing that it is writing to the browser.